# Accepted Offer, No Response From Company

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I received an offer through e-mail 2 weeks ago and was told that an e-mail reply is sufficient to accept the offer. I accepted the offer immediately, but since then didn't hear anything back from the company.

I followed up on this Tuesday but again didn't receive any response. The offer is set to expire mid next week so I'm getting little anxious due to lack of confirmation given.

Should I be worried? I only have the e-mail address of the recruiter so I can't call her either.

(This is for summer internship position at one of the big tech company.)

Comment: Are you 100% sure the offer was legitimate? You might want to research her company, make sure it's real, make sure she works for the company, and make sure that's really her email address.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a phone number, call them to see if there is anything remaining you need to do and if not when you should show up and where.

If not, send them back another email and  explain that if you do not hear back from them, you'll have to consider other opportunities. Be very polite. After sending said email, start looking for other opportunities immediately in case they never respond or respond back that they are not longer interested.